# How to write case expression inside merge statement to print the desired result

Tags: sql, oracle, case, sql-merge

```
    CREATE TABLE DELIGATE_DETAILS_MAIN 
       (    E_ID NUMBER(10,0), 
        COMPLETED_DATE TIMESTAMP (6), 
         CONSTRAINT PK_DELIGATE_DETAILS_MAIN PRIMARY KEY (E_ID));

Insert into deligate_details_main (E_ID,COMPLETED_DATE) values (1,to_timestamp('13-12-21 6:05:23.991000000 PM','DD-MM-RR fmHH12:fmMI:SSXFF AM'));
Insert into deligate_details_main (E_ID,COMPLETED_DATE) values (2,to_timestamp('13-12-21 6:05:24.019000000 PM','DD-MM-RR fmHH12:fmMI:SSXFF AM'));
Insert into deligate_details_main (E_ID,COMPLETED_DATE) values (3,to_timestamp('13-12-21 6:05:24.029000000 PM','DD-MM-RR fmHH12:fmMI:SSXFF AM'));
Insert into deligate_details_main (E_ID,COMPLETED_DATE) values (4,to_timestamp('13-12-21 10:46:00.015000000 PM','DD-MM-RR fmHH12:fmMI:SSXFF AM'));

CREATE TABLE CONTROL_MAIN 
   (    E_ID NUMBER(10,0), 
    E_SPEC VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT PK_CONTROL_MAIN PRIMARY KEY (E_ID));
     

Insert into CONTROL_MAIN (E_ID,E_SPEC) values (1,'SAP1');
Insert into CONTROL_MAIN (E_ID,E_SPEC) values (2,'FSAP');
Insert into CONTROL_MAIN (E_ID,E_SPEC) values (3,'SAP2');
Insert into CONTROL_MAIN (E_ID,E_SPEC) values (4,'SAP1-480');

CREATE TABLE QUESTION 
   (    E_ID NUMBER(10,0), 
    QUEST VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT PK_QUESTION PRIMARY KEY (E_ID));
     

Insert into QUESTION (E_ID,QUEST) values (1,'Yes');
Insert into QUESTION (E_ID,QUEST) values (2,'No');
Insert into QUESTION (E_ID,QUEST) values (3,'Yes');
Insert into QUESTION (E_ID,QUEST) values (4,'Yes');

CREATE TABLE DELIGATE_DETAILS_TRANS 
   (    D_ID NUMBER(10,0), 
    E_ID NUMBER(10,0), 
    COMPLETED_DATE_TRANS DATE, 
    OWNER_DETAIL VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT PK_DELIGATE_DETAILS_TRANS PRIMARY KEY (D_ID),
     CONSTRAINT FK_E_ID FOREIGN KEY (E_ID)
      REFERENCES TAM.DELIGATE_DETAILS_MAIN (E_ID));
```

Attempt:

```
MERGE INTO deligate_details_trans t USING ( SELECT
    ddm.e_id,
    ddm.completed_date
FROM
    deligate_details_main ddm
JOIN control_main cm ON ( cm.e_id = ddm.e_id AND cm.e_spec LIKE %'SAP'% )
    JOIN question      q ON ( q.e_id = ddm.e_id
                         AND q.quest = 'Yes' )
          ) s
    on (t.e_id = s.e_id)
    when not matched then
      insert (d_id,e_id, completed_date_trans, owner_detail)
      values (
    deligate_details_trans_sq.nextval,
    s.e_id,
    CAST(s.completed_date AS DATE),
--Here need to insert owner detail from control main
--If it is SAP1 or SAP2 then it will insert SAP1 or SAP2
--If it is SAP1-480 then it should insert SAP3);
```

Expected output:

```
+------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
| D_ID | E_ID    | COMPLETED_DATE_TRANS  | OWNER_DETAIL |
+------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
|    1 |       1 | 13-12-21              | SAP1         |
|    2 |       3 | 13-12-21              | SAP2         |
|    3 |       4 | 13-12-21              | SAP3         |
+------+---------+-----------------------+--------------+
```

For e_id 1: Based on the join condition from control_main and question table. Data should get inserted into the deligate_details_trans table and owner detail should be SAP1.

For e_id 2: Based on the join condition from control_main and question table. Data is NOT matching so it should not get inserted into the trans table.

For e_id 3: Based on the join condition from control_main and question table. Data should get inserted into the deligate_details_trans table and owner detail should be SAP2.

For e_id 4 it should check in the control main table and if it is SAP1-480 then it should insert SAP3 and for others, corresponding owner details should be inserted from the control_main table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the case expression in the insert's `values` clause then you need to expose the control table value in the `using` clause:

```
MERGE INTO deligate_details_trans t
USING (
    SELECT
        ddm.e_id,
        ddm.completed_date,
        cm.e_spec
    FROM
        deligate_details_main ddm
    JOIN control_main cm ON ( cm.e_id = ddm.e_id AND cm.e_spec LIKE '%SAP%' )
    JOIN question      q ON ( q.e_id = ddm.e_id
                         AND q.quest = 'Yes' )
) s
ON (t.e_id = s.e_id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    d_id,e_id, completed_date_trans, owner_detail
)
VALUES (
    deligate_details_trans_sq.nextval,
    s.e_id,
    CAST(s.completed_date AS DATE),
    CASE s.e_spec
        WHEN 'SAP1' THEN 'SAP1'
        WHEN 'SAP2' THEN 'SAP2'
        WHEN 'SAP1-480' THEN 'SAP3'
    END
);
```

Alternatively move the case expression into the `using` clause, give it an alias, and refer to that alias in the `values` clause:

```
MERGE INTO deligate_details_trans t
USING (
    SELECT
        ddm.e_id,
        ddm.completed_date,
        CASE cm.e_spec
            WHEN 'SAP1' THEN 'SAP1'
            WHEN 'SAP2' THEN 'SAP2'
            WHEN 'SAP1-480' THEN 'SAP3'
        END AS owner_detail
    FROM
        deligate_details_main ddm
    JOIN control_main cm ON ( cm.e_id = ddm.e_id AND cm.e_spec LIKE '%SAP%' )
    JOIN question      q ON ( q.e_id = ddm.e_id
                         AND q.quest = 'Yes' )
) s
ON (t.e_id = s.e_id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    d_id,e_id, completed_date_trans, owner_detail
)
VALUES (
    deligate_details_trans_sq.nextval,
    s.e_id,
    CAST(s.completed_date AS DATE),
    s.owner_detail
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6308d9b8b41bb5288a9da923d85d660b) showing both (with `%'SAP'%` changed to `'%SAP%'`, and sequence creation added).

---

I'm not sure why you have a timestamp in one table and a date in the other, and you don't need an explicit cast (though it doesn't hurt). But *if* you're doing that because you're only interested in the date part you should be aware that an Oracle date still has a time component, even if it isn't being shown in your DD-MM-YY format or db<>fiddle's default DD-MON-YY format. If you want to 'lose' the time part you can truncate the value at the day (DD) component, [shown in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=654ae7f4e22fdf9ecf75b30fe158ba99) which changes the display format so you can see the difference. But you might want to keep the time - in which case, ignore this part...

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. I saw you have edited the question and removed the dummy table which was incorrectly aligned. May I know how can I paste a dummy table from https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ while asking the question?

Comment: @Vicky - I changed it to a Markdown table; but could have kept your version from Senseful by enclosing it in a code fence - just put three backticks ``` on a line before and after the table, that will then be treated as code and will appear in monospace and aligned. (You can/should now do that for actual code, instead of indenting everything by four characters...) I've updated the question to show your original version so you can see what I mean.